# How to Conversion from “datetime-local” to mysql.Timestamp in javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, html

I'm trying to insert date value from "date-time-local" box to MySQL DB  in TIMESTAMP column. How should I convert the value to TIMESTAMP.

Comment: <input type="datetime-local" name="due_date" placeholder="Due date" required>

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items (
    
    due_date TIMESTAMP,
   
);

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript statement `new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');` would yield something like `2019-03-11 03:47:06`. The MySQL TIMESTAMP value has a range from '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC, hence where you hear about the 2038 problem, since the integers can only cover so much space, but that's off topic :)